# In Git, how do I see the host and port of the repo I'm currently working with?

Tags: git, bash, repository, port, hostname

In my Git Bash, how can I see the host and port of the repo that I'm "connected" to (i.e. the repo that my code is linked to)?

Comment: Please review the answer given below.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
git remote show origin
```

This will show you the fetch and push URLs of the `origin` remote which you have configured.  The URLs include the host and port.

Comment: @zviad The output includes the fetch and pull URLs, which show the host and port.

Answer (score 0):

`git remote -v` gives a list of all remotes you have configured, along with the URL's used.